# Subclipse workflow clarification

Tags: eclipse, workflow, subclipse

I have been using TortoiseSVN for a while now and just recently started using the eclipse plugin **subclipse**. I am really happy with it, although there is some stuff confusing me.

I have a few projects, which each have a different subfolder in the repository. I never worked with branches (so far), so my SVN use was fairly easy.

1. Update to head
2. Solve conflict if there are any
3. Make some changes in the code/project
4. Commit (Tortoise tells me, if an update is neccessary before)

Now with subclipse, I fell that there are other possibilities. For instance, what's with the synchronize view? I don't really get it. At the moment, I use `Team->Update to head/Commit` on the project folder and if there are conflicts, I use `Team->Edit conflicts...` on the conflicted file. That's it. So I never touch the synchronize stuff. I haven't really found a good explanation on the subclise page or google...

Is the idea to just synchronize and everything is done automatically or what?

Basically, I am asking for the workflow (or some link to a good basic explanation). I am not asking, what is possible or what does what, but how subclipse is **intended** to be used for small projects (<100 files, <5 persons working on it, no branches so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is any reason to use the Synchronize view if you do not want to.  I really like just doing Team > Update and then resolve whatever conflicts occur.  That is much more the "SVN-way" to do it.  The Synchronize view comes from Eclipse world, so Subclipse had to support it.

TortoiseSVN does have an option that is kind of/sort of like the Synchronize view.  It is the "Check for Modifications" option.  Particularly when you press the "Check Repository" button.

Also, keep in mind that the Synchronize view does not show "conflicts" the same way as SVN.  In SVN, a conflict means that it could not auto-merge the change in to your file.  In the Synchronize view, it means you have local modifications to a file that has incoming changes.  It is possible, perhaps even likely, that SVN could automatically merge those changes if you just did an update.  Personally, I would rather just let SVN try to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clarified a lot for me. (And also told me that its "ok" to use the "SVN-way" ^^).^

Answer (score 1):

The synchronization view allows you to recognize conflicts before you perform an update. If you perform an update and you are getting conflicts this means that you have to stop what you were doing before and start solving the conflicts. This is an interruption of your work-flow.

Usually if you perform an update and get conflict(s) you loose the ability to run and debug your program. using the synchronization view you can update the conflicting files one-by one, which allows you to integrate the remote changes step-by-step into your project.

Therefore you can start solving the conflict without loosing the ability to run your program. Or you see that there are many conflicts and decide that it is not a good time to perform an update at this time.

Hence the synchronization feature is very powerful if it comes to detecting, preventing or solving conflicting changes in an SVN.

Comment: Ok, so there are basically three versions of a file: my current version, the revision I have updated to and the head. But I can only see two of those version... (is `Remote File Base` the head of the repository or my latest update?). And how can I then react to conflicts? I am not able to directly access the files and there is also no rightclick on the differences (like in the tortoise edit conflict browser).

Comment: Ok, I begin to understand now... That's also the reason, why the "copy current change from left to right" is disabled. I cannot edit a revision, I would have to commit a new one... But I can take in the head to my local file. Wow, this is much more complicated than TortoiseSVN. You have to actually **think**...

Comment: If you don't update but compare the local and the remote version you can take over code from the remote versions before you update and the conflict occurs. After solving all problems you can update without conflicts and directly commit your new version.

Comment: I actually don't see where the conflicts are not occurring. You will have to take in the changes from the remote version (your terminology makes more sense then mine ^^) eventually to be able to commit, which will result in a conflict.